# Why is mentric totatAdRevenue not working?

Tags: google-analytics

When using metric totalAdRevenue (admanager 360 link in GA4) the metric 'totalAdRevenue' is not giving any results. In GA4 Query explorer i do get the right data.

My Code:

```
$ar = [
  'property' => 'properties/' . $PROP_ID,
  'dateRanges' => [
     new DateRange([
        'start_date' => $date->format("Y-m-d"),
        'end_date' =>  $date->format("Y-m-d"),
    ]),
  ],
  'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
      [
        'name' => 'sessionCampaignName'
      ]
    ),
  ],
  'metrics' => [new Metric(
      [
        'name' =>  'sessions'
      ]
    ), new Metric(
      [
        'name' =>  'totalAdRevenue'
      ]
    )
  ]
];
$response = $analytics->runReport($ar);
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: just campaign name and sessions. No revenue